# Visual Studio Online - Work items not displaying in sprint board properly?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Online to manage my project, it's setup as a Scrum project.

My question is, why can't I drag a work item or bug into the To Do, In Progress, or Done columns when viewing the board within a sprint?

I can drag tasks between the columns in a sprint board, but not work items or bugs.

If I go the main backlogs view and go to the board I can drag work items and bugs between columns, but in the board for a sprint this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "work item"? Do you mean a *product backlog item*? *Work Item* is a generic term.

Comment: For work item I mean "Product backlog item"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is an option within the sprint board to have bugs appear on the board with tasks.

In Visual Studio Online, go to your current sprint and select the board.

Click the settings button (gear wheel in top right of screen).

Under the General section select "Working with bugs".

Here you can choose "Bugs appear on the backlogs and boards with tasks.".

This allows bugs to be dragged between columns in your sprint board.

Bugs can now be children of Product Backlog Items.

Answer (score 1):

What you get is as expected. You can't drag Product Backlog or Bug on Sprint board.

You may be aware that, when dragging item on the board, from **To Do** column to **In Progress** column for example, the **State** for that work item is changed from **To Do** to **In Progress** as well. States on Sprint board are To Do, In Progress and Done, which are match Task's states not Product Backlog or Bug. So, you can't drag Product Backlog or Bug on Sprint board.

Comment: Thanks. That seems a bit limited though. If I view a sprint it means that in order to make use of the To Do, In Progress and Done columns, I have to create a task that can be moved between the columns. If my product backlog item only consists of one task that means I have to effectively duplicate the backlog item as a task 1:1. It sounds like a duplication of effort?

Comment: If you are only creating one task, then your backlog item is not really a backlog item! If it is not big enough to warrant a plan, then why are you getting the PO to prioritise it?

Comment: What if the backlog item is a bug? It might just need a simple fix but still needs to be recorded and tracked.

Comment: @MrHinsh by PO do you mean "Product Owner"?